# Substring method not returning max character limit

Tags: javascript, html, character, counting

When the character count is above the max limit (20 characters), the substring method returns the characters typed in the input from indices 0 to 20. The substring method overwrites everything the user tries to type over a character count of 20.

But in my program, I am able to type more characters after I reached my max limit. Why is that happening? I don't want that to happen.

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('textarea')
const message = document.querySelector('.message')

let maxLength = 20;
let warnLength = 15;

['keyup', 'keydown', 'change'].forEach(event => {
  txt.addEventListener(event, textCounter)
})

function textCounter() {
  let count = txt.value.length
  if (count > warnLength) {
    message.innerHTML = `${(maxLength-count)} characters left`
  } else if (count > maxLength) {
    txt.value = txt.value.substring(0, maxLength)
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400 px;
  height: 100 px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if (count > warnLength) { is always true after char 15

- testing count > warnLength && count <= maxLength will work
- testing maxLength first will work better
- using maxlength attribute will make the test for maxLength unnecessary
- if not, preventDefault will stop the entry:

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('textarea')
const message = document.querySelector('.message')

let maxLength = 20;
let warnLength = 15;

['keyup', 'keydown', 'change'].forEach(event => {
  txt.addEventListener(event, textCounter)
})

function textCounter(e) {
  let count = txt.value.length;
  if (count > maxLength) {
    e.preventDefault(); // will stop the entry
    //txt.value = txt.value.substring(0, maxLength)
  } else if (count > warnLength) {
    message.innerHTML = `${(maxLength-count)} characters left`
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400 px;
  height: 100 px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the `maxlength` property of the `<textarea>` and eliminate the substring part of your code altogether.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const max = textarea.getAttribute('maxlength');
const warn = 15;
const textCounter = () => {
  const count = textarea.value.length;
  if (count > warn) {
    message.innerHTML = `${(max - count)} characters left`;
  } else if (count <= warn) {
    message.innerHTML = '';
  }
};

textarea.addEventListener('input', textCounter);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400 px;
  height: 100 px;
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: DOH. Did not think of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the if condition:

```
if (count > maxLength) {
    txt.value = txt.value.substring(0, maxLength)
} else if (count > warnLength) {
    message.innerHTML = `${(maxLength-count)} characters left`
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear:) Because in your case the ```count > warnLength``` condition will always apply first, and it would skip the else if.

Comment: I moved your test around

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute of textarea tag called "maxlength"  where you can specify  the maximum number of characters allowed in the text area.

Just add the following line in your code:

```
txt.setAttribute("maxlength",maxLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add maxlength tom textarea like that

```
<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
```